# Прочитать длину данных из сокета c#

Tags: php, c#

У меня есть клиент на c# и сервер на php.
С сервера отправляю данные кодом

```
$Data = "test"
socket_write($msgsock, $Data, strlen($Data));
```

Принимаю на стороне c#

```
byte[] buffer_receive = new byte[1024];
bytesRec = socket.Receive(buffer_receive);
```

Но что если сервер отправит больше чем 1024 байт, каким образом считать неизвестное число байт полностью ?

Comment: Обернуть в `while` пока приходят не пустые данные просто делать конкатенацию. (ПС: Не .NET разработчик)

Comment: Если сделать так как вы сказали то при повтором вызове функции socket.Receive если в предыдущий раз считался весь объем данных программа зависает.

Comment: Передавайте сначала длину, а потом сообщение.

Comment: Была такая мысль, но встал вопрос сколько байт выделять под значение длины, и неужели нет более изящного решения

Comment: @LorDo: Это как вы решите, я обычно использую 4 байта. Изящного решения нет, т. к. TCP — потоковое соединение, и в нем нет понятия границы между сообщениями.

Comment: А как вы добиваетесь фиксированного размера в 4 байта. Например если сделать socket_write($msgsock, strlen($Data)+$Data, strlen($Data)+strlen(strlen($Data))); то strlen($Data) может оказаться как 300 так и 2000 т.е. разная длина самой длины, простите за тафтологию

Comment: Вобщем на стороне php сделал вот так:                                                                         
          $Data = "test"

   $Lenght = unpack("C*", pack("L", strlen($Data)));
   $MsgHead = pack("CCCC", $Lenght[1], $Lenght[2], $Lenght[3], $Lenght[4]);
   
   socket_write($msgsock, $MsgHead, strlen($MsgHead));   
   socket_write($msgsock, $Data, strlen($Data));

Comment: В php можно перевести длину в hex, дорастить нулями до нужной длины и потом упаковать.

Comment: @LorDo: 4 байта — это длина стандартного `int` в C#.